# Extract names of dataframes in a list passed to a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have a list of timeseries objects which are being passed to a function for forecast. I want to extract the name of each timeseries in the function and use it for plot title.

```
  list.ts <- lapply(list.df , FUN=create.ts)


Fcst.model <- function(my.ts, nameofdf = substr(my.ts[i],start = 1,stop = str_length(my.ts[i]))){
    #my arima model
    plot(arimaMod.Fr,   ylab="", xlab="Months", col="red", main = nameofdf)  
}
```

```
n <- length(list.ts)
  for (i in 1:n){
  lapply(list.ts , FUN=Fcst.model)
}
```

I also tried using main = deparse(substitue(my.ts)  but it gave me the output as X[1]

Comment: This might work `purrr::imap(list.ts, plot_func)` where `plot_func <- function(df, name) plot(df,   ylab="", xlab="Months", col="red", main = name)  
`

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`purrr::imap` comes in handy in this type of case where we need to iterate over the  list of elements (or atomic vectors) and their names parallelly:

`purrr::imap(list.ts, plot_func)`

where 
`plot_func <- function(df, name) plot(df, ylab="", xlab="Months", col="red", main = name)`